# How to trace a 400 error in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I can't find where the error is. A similar code to pull dynamic file name worked in another tab.

```
Sub MonthlyBCRCPL()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim CardsRCPLWb As Workbook
    Set CardsRCPLWb = ActiveWorkbook
    filePath = CardsRCPLWb.Sheets("BCRCPL").Range("A1").Value

    'Optimize Code
    Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    Const FlashFolder As String = "\\apacdfs\SG\GCGR\GROUPS\ASEAN\Dashboard\Cards\Flash\"
    Flashname = Format(CardsRCPLWb.Sheets("ASEAN - CARDS, RCPL").Range("C2").Value, "YYYYMMDD")
    Flashname = "ASEAN SD Regional Dashboard - " & Flashname & ".xlsx"
    Flashpath = FlashFolder & Flashname
    Dim FlashWb As Workbook
    Set FlashWb = Workbooks.Open(Flashpath)
    If FlashWb Is Nothing Then MsgBox "SD Flash File does not exist": Exit Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: Check whether the File exists with Dir() method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [handling the error](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) in the subroutine and have it raise a message. Then, properly continues/skips/exits rest of code even releasing objects from memory caught during the exception. This is a best practice in VBA (and generally in programming).

I suspect the path cannot be found which looks to be a network UNC, file naming is not valid such as use of special characters, or workbook does not exist when trying to open:

```
Sub MonthlyBCRCPL()
   On Error Goto ErrHandle:
   ...code...

ExitSubBlock:    
   Set CardsRCPLWb = Nothing
   Set FlashWb = Nothing
   Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
   Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
   Goto ExitSubBlock
   ' Resume Next       
End Sub
```